# How can I get a specific data from database within the range using Sequilize

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

```
const minPoint = 20
for (let key in modelKnowledge) {
    if(modelKnowledge.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if (minPoint == modelKnowledge[key].min_point) {
            knowledgePoint = modelKnowledge[key].point
            console.log(knowledgePoint)
        }
    }
}
```

[This is my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbRN0.png)

For example my minPoint is 20 so its in the range of 17 and 24 in the database (as min_point). So I want it to bring me the point of 17 (that is 0.75). If my minPoint was 40 I would want to get the min_point 37's point which is 2.5. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure I fully understood your question but you can use [sequelize operators](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-querying-basics.html#operators):

```
await modelKnowledge.findAll({
  where: {
    min_point: {
      [Op.gt]: minPoint // gt = greater than
    }
  }
}).then((results) => {
  results.forEach(result => {
    console.log(result.point) // This would print point from rows 2-17 in your database
  }
})
```

To get all rows in the database with a min_point > minPoint

To get only ones in a range you can use [Op.between]:

```
await modelKnowledge.findAll({
  where: {
    min_point: {
      [Op.between]: [minPoint, minPoint + 10]
    }
  }
}).then((results) => {
  results.forEach(result => {
    console.log(result.point) // This would print point from rows 2-5 in your database
  }
})
```

From what you asked I dont think this is what you wanted, since you wanted the closest to the min point (I think), you'd have to run a function to get the closest point from a given range.